# Recaptcha does not work locally

Tags: php, captcha

There is absolutely no errors in coding, it just does not seem to work locally, but works perfectly online.  It is important I get it working locally because of development purposes.  Not form submission, but page display.

Any ideas on how I cam make the recaptcha to work locally.

Thanks
Jean

Comment: I think you are not talking about offline but "locally" as in localhost.... am I right?

Comment: Bad question. Add details: what error/wrong behaviour you get, post a snippet of your source code, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Recaptcha is an online web service, thus it will work only online.
You cannot make it work offline.

*Edit*:
Your problem seems not to be your internet connection but a PHP error, since your comment talks about a "white page". Please search the web (or stackoverflow) for "php white page" to get debugging instructions.

Comment: I am connected to the internet

Comment: Well then surely it can't be offline?

Comment: its http://localhost/xx so thats offline, but the page shows blank. copy/paste their example code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using XAMPP, if so, I found that if you put your files in htdocs in XAMPP folder the recaptcha works. According to google, their recaptcha will work on localhost. I'm sure there's a lot more logical solution than what I have, but this is what worked for me, hope it helps you too.